# Using autocorr in Matlab with matrix input?

Tags: matrix, matlab

As described in the help:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/econ/autocorr.html#btzja9w-1

autocorr expects the input y to be a uni-variate time series.

Is there a multi-variate equivalent?

I have an n*m array and I would like to calculate the lag(1) auto correlation along each row.
Obviously I can work round by splitting the matrix up into univariate series and then inputting them individually, but just wondered if there was a neater solution?

Thanks

Baz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the econometrics toolbox to test this but what about:

```
bsxfun(@crosscorr, M, permute(M, [1,3,2]))
```

or maybe

```
ACF_1 = @(x,y)(crosscorr(x,y,1));
bsxfun(ACF_1, M, permute(M, [1,3,2]))
```